# Proving system of equations has unique solution using contraction mapping principle

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, contraction-operator

I am trying to prove that the linear system $x = Ax + b$ has a unique solution using the contraction mapping principle, where $$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} &  \frac{2}{15} \\
  \frac{1}{4} &  \frac{1}{5} &  \frac{1}{2}  \\
 -\frac{1}{4} &  \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
~~\text{ and }~~
b = \begin{pmatrix}
  3 \\
 -1 \\
  2 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Toward this end, I've defined the map $f(x) = Ax + b$ with the next logical step being to prove that $\forall x,y \in R^3 \times R^3$ that $$
\|f(x) - f(y)\| = \|A(x - y)\| \le \|A\|\|x-y\|
$$
and $\|A\| < 1$. But I'm not sure how to prove that $\|A\| < 1$.

One thing I notice here is that the L2-norms of the rows of $A$ are all less than one, and the L2-norms of the columns of $A$ are all less than one. Is this sufficient to prove the claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe here you have
\begin{align}
\|A(x-y)\|_2 \leq \|A\|_\text{op}\|x-y\|_2
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\|A\|_\text{op} = \sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}(A) \leq \left(\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}|a_{ij}|^2\right)^{1/2} =\sqrt{\frac{39}{50}}<1
\end{align}
where $\sigma_\text{max}(A)$ denotes the largest singular value of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it suffices to prove that $\|A\|<1$ for *some* submultiplicative norm. The norm doesn't have to be the induced $2$-norm.

Here, the sum of moduli of entries on each row of $A$ is smaller than $1$:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
\frac14+\frac14+\frac2{15}&<\frac14+\frac14+\frac28<1,\\ \frac14+\frac15+\frac12&<\frac14+\frac14+\frac12=1,\\
\frac14+\frac13+\frac13&<\frac13+\frac13+\frac13=1.
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Hence $\|A\|_\infty=\max_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|<1$ and $A$ is a contraction map.